# SQL SERVER Group Datetimestamps by Month

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, group-by

I've got intervaldata (Value) each 15 minutes for the last 3 years.
The datatype for the datetimestamp is datetimeoffset(7).
The datetimestamp for each interval has to be interpreted as the end of the timeperiod.

For example, the Value 1.96 at datetimestamp 2017-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 +01:00 is the period
from 2016-12-31 23:45:00.0000000 +01:00 to 2017-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 +01:00

```
DateTime                            Value
2016-12-31 23:00:00.0000000 +01:00  2.0000000000
2016-12-31 23:15:00.0000000 +01:00  1.9600000000
2016-12-31 23:30:00.0000000 +01:00  2.0400000000
2016-12-31 23:45:00.0000000 +01:00  2.0000000000
2017-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 +01:00  1.9600000000
2017-01-01 00:15:00.0000000 +01:00  2.1200000000
2017-01-01 00:30:00.0000000 +01:00  2.0800000000
2017-01-01 00:45:00.0000000 +01:00  2.0000000000
2017-01-01 01:00:00.0000000 +01:00  2.0000000000
```

I'd like to know the total per month. The query below gives me wrong results because the datetimestamp 2017-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 +01:00 is added to january 2017 instead of december 2016.

```
SELECT Year([datetimestamp])  AS [Year], 
       Month([datetimestamp]) AS [Month], 
       Sum([value])           AS [Total] 
FROM   [data] 
GROUP  BY Year([datetimestamp]), 
          Month([datetimestamp]) 
ORDER  BY [year], 
          [month]
```

Comment: Convert to UTC?

Comment: :sigh: This is why (normally) you _don't_ store things with an "end" period, you do it with a "start" period.  It makes it so that, if you change the resolution of the timing, you need no special signifiers (ie, if your resolution goes to 1 second, @LukStorms answer will no longer work).  It allows dynamic, variable, periods much easier.  This is because time is (most easily thought of as) continuous - that is, there is no such thing as an "end" instant, only a start and a length (to some resolution).  Any time you record an "end", it's really the start of something else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you subtract a minute then it would yield the correct year and month for the group by?

```
SELECT 
 YEAR(Dt) AS [Year],
 MONTH(Dt) AS [Month],
 SUM([Value]) AS [Total]
FROM (
  SELECT
   DATEADD(MINUTE, -1, [datetimestamp]) AS Dt,
   [Value]
  FROM [data]
) q
GROUP BY YEAR(Dt), MONTH(Dt)
ORDER BY [Year], [Month];
```

Or without sub-query

```
SELECT 
 YEAR(DATEADD(MINUTE, -1, [datetimestamp])) AS [Year],
 MONTH(DATEADD(MINUTE, -1, [datetimestamp])) AS [Month],
 SUM([Value]) AS [Total]
FROM [data]
GROUP BY YEAR(DATEADD(MINUTE, -1, [datetimestamp])), 
         MONTH(DATEADD(MINUTE, -1, [datetimestamp]))
ORDER BY [Year], [Month];
```

Comment: @ZoharPeled The OP said that the data is fixed per 15 minutes interval. So looking at that data it doesn't matter if you do -15 or -1. The point is to get that '2017-01-01 00:00:00' in the previous year.

Comment: yes, but you are relying on accurate timestamps here. I get that it will work for this scenario but if the timestamps was a little bit less accurate, the 1 minute might not be enough.

Comment: True, but I'll see what the OP says about it.  Seems that those timestamps without seconds are batch generated.

Answer (score 1):

You might find this easier to express

```
SELECT YEAR(dts_start) AS [Year],
       MONTH(dts_start) AS [Month],
       SUM([Value]) AS [Total]
FROM data CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (DATEADD(minute, -15, datetimestamp)) as v(dts_start)
GROUP BY YEAR(dts_start), MONTH(dts_start)
ORDER BY [Year], [Month];
```

You might also find `FORMAT()` convenient:

```
SELECT FORMAT(dts_start, 'yyyy-MM') AS yyyymm,
       SUM([Value]) AS [Total]
FROM data CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (DATEADD(minute, -15, datetimestamp)) as v(dts_start)
GROUP BY FORMAT(dts_start, 'yyyy-MM')
ORDER BY yyyymm;
```

Comment: Really?  Grouping by a text formatting?  Although doing the date/time math is probably removing the ability to hit an index anyways....